# > That was what I **do/did** - If I did something that I usually do even now, should I use "do" or "did"?

Tags: tense

**Example 1**

> That was what I **do/did**.

If I did something that I usually do even now, should I use "do" or "did"?

If I use "did," can it mean I currently still do that instead of just referring to the past?

Answer (score 1):

"That was what I **did**" is the only fluent way to phrase the sentence.  The tenses of the verbs (*was/did*) need to match: if you are talking about something in the past ("That *was*...") then the doing was also in the past ("...what I *did*.")

Saying *did* does not directly state that you don't do it any more, but it does kind of imply it.  If you need to specify that it is something you still do, you might say something like

> That was what I did, and still do

or

> That was what I did, as I still do.

Comment: You may also achieve the meaning of something starting in the past and continuing into the present by saying "That is what I have been doing."